# Is it possible to show the values for all keys in sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt

Is it possible to dump all keys and values in sbt?

Like this:

```
> show libraryDependencies
[info] List(org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.10.3, com.github.nscala-time:nscala-time:0.6.0)
```

But for all of the keys in the build?

Comment: Actually this is a bit more complex question than you may think. There is no single value for a key within the build. There are multiple [scope axes](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Getting-Started/Scopes.html#scope-axes), where the same key would have different value. Additionally for tasks using `show <task-name>` makes them being evaluated, which may be potentially harmless (think stuff being published on-line or tasks which have side effects). I think that this may be a reason why this is not implemented in sbt.

Comment: That looks like a pretty good answer to me, any reason you left it as a comment? :)

Comment: I wasn't sure if it answers your question, if you feel so, I can make it an answer ;).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's possible. Actually this is a bit more complex question than you may think.

There is no single value for a key within the build. There are multiple [scope axes](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Getting-Started/Scopes.html#scope-axes), where the same key would have different value.

Additionally for tasks using `show <task-name>` makes them being evaluated, which may be potentially harmless (think stuff being published on-line or tasks which have side effects in your file system).

I think that this may be a reason why this is not implemented in sbt.